# what do I need to do with "man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct"

Tags: linux, man

I typed `man sudoers` but got

```
man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
No manual entry for sudoers
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I had similar problem on OS X and was able to fix it by commenting out `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your locale isn't set. In `Debian-Base` you should use `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to set it.

Some of `packages` depend on `locales package` and its `variable` such as `LC_* series` ...!

It means `$LANG` is empty.

Comment: On my system `$LANG` wasn't empty when I got the message from `man`. I ran `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and let it process, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 9):

Your locale settings as indicated by environment variables uses locale names that are not available on your system.

Locale settings control the character set used by commands and terminals (`LC_CTYPE`), the collation order (`LC_COLLATE`), the format of dates (`LC_TIME`), numbers (`LC_NUMERIC`) and amounts of currency (`LC_MONETARY`), the language of messages (`LC_MESSAGES`), etc. The values of these variables are locale names. On most systems, the name has the form `xx_YY` or `xx_YY@variant` or `xx_YY.charset` where `xx` is a two-letter [language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) and `YY` is a two-letter [country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

Run the command `locale` to see your current settings.
Run `locale -a` to see the available locale names.

If the locale you'd like to use is missing, you may need to generate it. This is distribution-dependent. For example, on Debian, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root. On Ubuntu, run `locale-gen xx_YY` to generate the locale `xx_YY`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an addition to the recommendation to use `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, which failed for me (my hunch is that if it were working, I wouldn't have this problem.

The problem

```
me@pc:~$ man
man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
What manual page do you want?
```

First try to solve it, fails

```
me@pc:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  ...(lines omitted)...
```

Second try, succeeds. I still get an error on en_ZW, but I don't use it.

```
me@pc:~$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 && sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
...
me@pc:~$ man
what manual page do you want?
```

No more LOCALE errors on the man command!

Answer (score 2):

This means your system does not know in which language the info should be displayed.

Paste the output of locale -a probably you haven`t generated the locales this is a *bit* distro specific but usually running locale-gen will generate the locales for you hence removing the error. Take a look on this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale).

Answer (score 1):

Still a problem in 2020... On my system (Kubuntu 20.04.1), the solution was simply `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` in my `~/.zshrc`. I imagine the same would work in `.bashrc`.

I think there are other variables which need to be set (probably those reported by `locales`), but they seem to have all been handled by the desktop environment.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a raspberry pi, this can also be fixed by using `sudo raspi-config`, selecting "Localisation Options", and then setting your appropriate locale.