# Problems with the locale; can't make Arch Linux use UFT-8

Tags: arch-linux, locale, unicode

**Note:** The real problems behind this are presented [he](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111020/how-can-i-set-the-keyboard-right-on-x)[re](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111037/how-can-i-make-the-tty-use-the-appropriate-charset), as per a [recommendation](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/is-it-ok-to-massively-edit-a-question-after-receiving-a-couple-responses#answer-2657) on meta. This question should be closed as a non-reproducible off-topic because its main problem is solved by correcting a typo.

---

Hi fellows,

I have tried to follow various [official](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale) tutorials and [questions](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166041) and supposed [solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12501/weird-stuff-in-terminal-when-i-hit-tab) (a few only appliying to, say [Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53733/man-gives-the-error-about-locale) [based](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114759/warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale) distros), none of which worked. Adding things like `LANG="pt_PT.UFT-8"` in `~/.bashrc` didn/t work either, although it quiets the [`man` warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87116/what-do-i-need-to-do-with-man-cant-set-the-locale-make-sure-lc-and-lang) (but generated a few warnings like `bash: can't set $LC_CTYPE (...)` loading the shell after login):

```
man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

My `locale.conf` file, which BTW has experienced a lot of combinations of `LC*` and `LANG*` variables:

```
LANG="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LANGUAGE="pt_PT.UFT-8"
```

The result of some other commands:

```
[jmcf125@jmcf125-Toshiba-Arch ~]$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=pt_PT.UFT-8
LC_CTYPE="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_TIME="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_NAME="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_PT.UFT-8"
LC_ALL=

[jmcf125@jmcf125-Toshiba-Arch ~]$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
pt_PT.utf8
[jmcf125@jmcf125-Toshiba-Arch ~]$ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=pt_PT.UFT-8
       VC Keymap: pt-latin9
      X11 Layout: pt
```

`locale.gen` (no comments):

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
pt_PT.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

`locale-gen` has always returned:

```
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8
  pt_PT.UTF-8
Generation complete.
```

I have also tried `uft8` instead of `UFT-8` (that was part of the Ubuntu solution I used back then), with no good results (although I didn't try it in many places).

Besides, the keyboard on X is not `pt-latin9`, even if I do `loadkeys pt-latin9` and related commands, although that's not my main problem right now. That is another question. The current problem is that Non ASCII characters are not displayed right (not in the tty, much less in X).

For example, if I click the key for c cedilla, I get a majuscule `A` with a trema, and I can delete am additional character of the prompt with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>! I suspect this is because the TTY expects 2 bytes to be 2 characters, and allows for an extra backspace. While `ls` gives a question mark per byte of the character (example: `Transfer??ncias`), `Tab` completion gives `Transferências/` on X and something else (other non ASCII character) on a TTY.

I hope you can help me, this is really annoying and I don't know what else to do. Even while writing this question, I mistyped `'` for `/` almost every time!

Comment: Seems your mistyping is causing you more problems than you intially thought...

Comment: @jasonwryan, I certainly did not see this coming. I feel so stupid right now...

Comment: We all do stupid things; the trick is to only do them once... :)

Comment: The worst is this isn't over, the TTY still displays wrong characters (others instead of `??`, but still), the keyboard is the same way (wrong in X and TTY), the only thing that works is the printing of Unicode characters on X. Now to take the typos out of here...

Comment: **Important note:** rolled back as recommended [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/is-it-ok-to-massively-edit-a-question-after-receiving-a-couple-responses#answer-2657). I'll fork this ASAP.

Comment: **[Forking](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111020/how-can-i-set-the-keyboard-right-on-x) [complete](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111037/how-can-i-make-the-tty-use-the-appropriate-charset)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `locale -a` is telling you that you have a locale named `pt_PT.utf8`.  But you keep trying to use `pt_PT.UFT-8`, which doesn't exist.  Use

```
LANG="pt_PT.utf8"
LANGUAGE="pt_PT.utf8"
```

`pt_PT.UTF-8` should work also, but it's `UTF-8`, not `UFT-8`.  The T comes before the F.

Comment: I did that quite a long time ago, and have discovered how to set the keyboard right in the X. Can you help me find out how to change the charset of the TTY?

Comment: Please see [the](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111020/how-can-i-set-the-keyboard-right-on-x) [forks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111037/how-can-i-make-the-tty-use-the-appropriate-charset).