# How can I make the TTY use the appropriate charset?

Tags: arch-linux, console, tty, keyboard-layout, unicode

**Note:** forked of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109053/problems-with-the-locale-cant-make-arch-linux-use-uft-8) per recommendation [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/is-it-ok-to-massively-edit-a-question-after-receiving-a-couple-responses#answer-2657).

---

While I [got the X keyboard layout right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111020/how-can-i-set-the-keyboard-right-on-x) on my own after I fixed that [stupid typo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109053/problems-with-the-locale-cant-make-arch-linux-use-uft-8), I still can't set the console charset, key map, font map, or whatever you want to call it; even considering 
[all](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_Configuration_in_Console) 
[info]
[on] the Arch wiki.

For example, if I click the key for <kbd>Ç</kbd> (c cedilla), I get a damn `Ä` (majuscule `A` with a trema), `Tab` completion also gives this **wrong** non ASCII character on a TTY.

I know the keyboard is right, if I pipe correct UTF-8 characters to a TTY, I get them wrong, and if I do it the other way around, they become right (say, to `/dev/pts/0`).

I heard the console only has support for 128 (or is it 256?) characters at a time, but those can be set. I tried setting `FONT_MAP` on `/etc/vconsole.conf`, with no results. The file is now:

```
KEYMAP=pt-latin9
FONT=Lat2-Terminus16
FONT_MAP=8859-2
```

I think would solve the problem are those `MAP` variables. The worst is that these variables are poorly documented, both in the Arch Wiki, and in the `vconsole.conf` manual pages:

```
FONT=, FONT_MAP=, FONT_UNIMAP=
    Configures the console font, the console map and the unicode font map.
```

How can I set them?

Regarding other methods, I'm a bit confused of how I can apply what is in some of the 
[more](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys) 
[advanced](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys_in_Console) 
[articles](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes). So far, I have simply copied `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/pt-latin9.map.gz` to `/usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/`, `gunzip`ed it, and read it while scratching my head.

I'm sorry, even though I've had this problem since I have Arch as my system, this is to hard for me to find the solution on my own; so I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please don't use greetings such as "good evening". When people later read this it won't make much sense. 8-). Though in looking at your logo I finally realized that I recognized it and I think we had this conversation before. So if you feel so inclined, do so, I seem to remember you mentioning it as a cultural thing (perhaps?). But don't get upset if they are later removed. It's a common practice to remove salutations and/or greetings and thanks on SE sites.

Comment: When you say TTY & console do you mean the terminal consoles accessible when you use the key combo Ctrl + Alt + F2, etc., or do you mean the pseudo terminal within say gnome-terminal?

Comment: @slm, I don't usually get upset, and never rollback, unless it's the only thing a user does, just to collect rep (which is not your case, you are 2k+ and gave a good reason, indeed it is an odd greeting `:S`; I'll refrain from using it). And yes, I'm that guy `:)` Enough of these matters, I stress TTY (instead of always saying console) because I mean the real terminal, not an emulator, sorry if it is confusing. Should I add a note about that in this question?

Comment: In the comments should be enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

it seems your console is not set to unicode.

what is the ouput of `stty`?
it should say "iutf8"; if not, try running on console `stty iutf8` and see if that solves your problem (you may need to reload the font after setting the terminal)